# Is this a bug in Rebol?

Tags: rebol

When copying and pasting a source code with ask instruction in Rebol console, the ask instruction paused the program to let me enter the answer. This for former Rebol version. Now not anymore, the program continues !

Is this a bug ?

Comment: Please be more specific on the versions of REBOL involved and add a stripped-down example illustrating your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to reproduce your issue using v2.7.6.3.1, the pasted line after an "ask" would feed it and the next EOL sequence will pass it, so it doesn't stop. This behaviour looks logical to me.

If you think that's a bug or a regression, fill a ticket in [RAMBO](http://www.rebol.net/cgi-bin/rambo.r).

Comment: This behavior may be usefull in automating test but annoying when testing interactively. I have to copy and paste the code in several steps.